# MySql Multiple output when using CASE in a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

When using case, how can I get two things out in the result?

Eg:

```
set @x = 1;

select case when UserId = @x 
then
concat('Test'), // This is the part I fail at. It'll output either one, but not more.
userName 
end from my_members;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two `case` statements:

```
set @x = 1;

select (case when UserId = @x then concat('Test') end) as col1
       (case when UserId = @x then userName end) as userName
from my_members;
```

Personally, I do wish that `case` statements allowed multiple column returns, but that would require a lot of changes to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use  `@x` as a filter predicate and then replace both / all the branches of your `CASE` with a `UNION` which selectively targets each of the branches, e.g.:

```
select UserId, concat('Test', userName) as userName
from my_members
WHERE UserId = @x

UNION 

select UserId, userName
from my_members
WHERE UserId <> @x;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02694/3)